# How to sort array based on length and alphabet, where alphabet takes precedence over length python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array here of 5 elements:

```
["@note1", "@note2", "=dir1/", "=dir2/", "@dir1/note1", "@dir1/note2"]
```

I want to sort them based on the characters and length but the characters will take precedence over the length

Example output of the sorted array should look like this:

```
["=dir1/","@dir1/note1", "@dir1/note2", "=dir2/", "@note1", "@note2"]
```

Right now i have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    s = ["@note1", "@note2", "=dir1/", "=dir2/", "@dir1/note1", "@dir1/note2"]
    s.sort()
    s.sort(key=len , reverse=True)
```

Is there a way to do it with this sorting function from python or do i have to make a custom sorting algorithm to do it?

Comment: Could you explain your output, what do you mean by alphabet takes precedence? `"=" < "@"`, besides you are putting the longs string first....

Comment: If you are looking to have shorter strings first, you don't need to sort by length at all (string comparisons already do that).  If by 'alphabet takes precedence' you mean to  ignore some (or all) of the non-letters in your strings, then would you only count the letters for the length ?  Also, would you only exclude the leading non-letters in the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sort key with a tuple:

```
d = ["@note1", "@note2", "=dir1/", "=dir2/", "@dir1/note1", "@dir1/note2"]
new_d = sorted(d, key=lambda x:(x[1:], len(x)))
```

Output:

```
['=dir1/', '@dir1/note1', '@dir1/note2', '=dir2/', '@note1', '@note2']
```